# Ionic2 - How to get a common / global SCSS file get compiled into build/main.css?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have the following brand new project, created with:

```
$ ionic start MyIonic2Project sidemenu --v2
```

[image]

The content of the file: `src/assets/css/style.scss` is the following:

```
img.avatar {
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

As you can see the above styles are embeded inside the `html` file, not in the file: `build/main.css`.

How do I get these styles inside the `main.css` file?

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

Cut the below code where it locates

```
img.avatar {
max-width: 100px;
max-height: 100px;
border-radius: 50%;
```

}

and paste it into build/main.css file.

Comment: but I think is not a good idea to write to the `build`/main.css file because this file should be generated automatically. That's why I was asking on how to add that css to some file inside the `src` or `resources` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You must write in index.html , it is work